Implementing pytorch temporal fusion transformer on time series
I am trying to run the temporal fusion transformer from the pytorch package. I am trying to compare the output on like terms to the tensorflow output in this paper p. 15 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.09363 the 50th and 90th quantiles.
I run the following code, trying to get output using two different modes but I don't understand what the output is supposed to represent. Can you please let me know how to interpret it and how to get the output that I am looking for?
Sorry my formatting is a bit off. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

df.categorical_time_on_day = df.categorical_time_on_day.astype(str)

df.categorical_day_of_week = df.categorical_day_of_week.astype(str)

df.sensor_day = df.sensor_day.astype(str)

df.categorical_id = df.categorical_id.astype(str)


# Set the date column as the index
#df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

max_prediction_length = 24

max_encoder_length = 168

#training_cutoff = data["time_idx"].max() - max_prediction_length

training = TimeSeriesDataSet(

    df,

    time_idx="hours_from_start",

    target="values",

    group_ids=["categorical_id"],

    min_encoder_length=max_encoder_length  // 2,  # keep encoder length long (as it is in the validation set)

    max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,

    min_prediction_length=1,

    max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length,

    #static_categoricals=["categorical_id"],

    #static_reals=["avg_population_2017", "avg_yearly_household_income_2017"],

    time_varying_known_categoricals=["categorical_time_on_day", "categorical_day_of_week","sensor_day"],

   # variable_groups={"special_days": special_days},  # group of categorical variables can be treated as one variable

    time_varying_known_reals=["prev_values"],

    #time_varying_unknown_categoricals=[],

    #time_varying_unknown_reals=[
    #    "volume",
    #    "log_volume",
    #    "industry_volume",
    #    "soda_volume",
    #    "avg_max_temp",
    #    "avg_volume_by_agency",
    #    "avg_volume_by_sku",
    #],

    target_normalizer=GroupNormalizer(
        groups=["categorical_id"], transformation="softplus"
    ),  # use softplus and normalize by group

    add_relative_time_idx=False,

    add_target_scales=False,

    add_encoder_length=False,
)

# create validation set (predict=True) which means to predict the last max_prediction_length points in time

# for each series
test = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, df, predict=True, stop_randomization=True)

# create dataloaders for model

batch_size = 128  #128  # set this between 32 to 128

train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)

test_dataloader = test.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size * 10, num_workers=0)

# configure network and trainer
pl.seed_everything(42)


trainer = pl.Trainer(
    accelerator="cpu",

    max_epochs=100,

    enable_model_summary=True,

    # clipping gradients is a hyperparameter and important to prevent divergance
    # of the gradient for recurrent neural networks
    gradient_clip_val=100 #from 0.1
)

hidden_size = 16


tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    training,

    # not meaningful for finding the learning rate but otherwise very important
    learning_rate=0.001,

    hidden_size=hidden_size,  # most important hyperparameter apart from learning rate
    # number of attention heads. Set to up to 4 for large datasets
    attention_head_size=4,

    dropout=0.3,  # between 0.1 and 0.3 are good values

    hidden_continuous_size=hidden_size,  # set to <= hidden_size

    loss=QuantileLoss(),

    optimizer="adam"

    # reduce learning rate if no improvement in validation loss after x epochs
    # reduce_on_plateau_patience=1000,
)

print(f"Number of parameters in network: {tft.size()/1e3:.1f}k")

predictions = tft.predict(test_dataloader, mode = "quantiles", return_y=True)

predictions```

which gives:

INFO: GPU available: False, used: False
INFO:lightning.pytorch.utilities.rank_zero:GPU available: False, used: False
INFO: TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
INFO:lightning.pytorch.utilities.rank_zero:TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
INFO: HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
INFO:lightning.pytorch.utilities.rank_zero:HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
WARNING: Missing logger folder: /content/lightning_logs
WARNING:lightning.pytorch.loggers.tensorboard:Missing logger folder: /content/lightning_logs
Prediction(output=tensor([[[0.0330, 0.0346, 0.0266, 0.0362, 0.0375, 0.0689, 0.0364],
         [0.0761, 0.0426, 0.0341, 0.0446, 0.0522, 0.0253, 0.0662],
         [0.0307, 0.0386, 0.0391, 0.0653, 0.0517, 0.0517, 0.0469],
         [0.0371, 0.0421, 0.0346, 0.0317, 0.0463, 0.0788, 0.0365],
         [0.0256, 0.0466, 0.0452, 0.0526, 0.0898, 0.0388, 0.0578],
         [0.0425, 0.0272, 0.0325, 0.0922, 0.0923, 0.0455, 0.0418],
         [0.0381, 0.0326, 0.0362, 0.0779, 0.0669, 0.0574, 0.0438],
         [0.0468, 0.0299, 0.0340, 0.0567, 0.0409, 0.0568, 0.0470],
         [0.0320, 0.0359, 0.0277, 0.0580, 0.0631, 0.0613, 0.0467],
         [0.0741, 0.0375, 0.0369, 0.0467, 0.0379, 0.0307, 0.0513],
         [0.0483, 0.0328, 0.0356, 0.0672, 0.0500, 0.0530, 0.0455],
         [0.0304, 0.0296, 0.0501, 0.0340, 0.0580, 0.0575, 0.0743],
         [0.0451, 0.0250, 0.0379, 0.0563, 0.0381, 0.0484, 0.0425],
         [0.0673, 0.0318, 0.0561, 0.0323, 0.0388, 0.0343, 0.0729],
         [0.0458, 0.0311, 0.0341, 0.0680, 0.0522, 0.0557, 0.0461],
         [0.0377, 0.0232, 0.0357, 0.0614, 0.0481, 0.0731, 0.0454],
         [0.0348, 0.0280, 0.0349, 0.0633, 0.0542, 0.0671, 0.0458],
         [0.0480, 0.0312, 0.0366, 0.0769, 0.0614, 0.0491, 0.0456],
         [0.0427, 0.0302, 0.0336, 0.0680, 0.0525, 0.0616, 0.0456],
         [0.0388, 0.0306, 0.0283, 0.0855, 0.0629, 0.0661, 0.0379],
         [0.0467, 0.0463, 0.0365, 0.0756, 0.0919, 0.0376, 0.0466],
         [0.0288, 0.0301, 0.0322, 0.0827, 0.0968, 0.0543, 0.0427],
         [0.0416, 0.0608, 0.0332, 0.0338, 0.0371, 0.0683, 0.0340],
         [0.0352, 0.0335, 0.0307, 0.0950, 0.0811, 0.0558, 0.0361]],

        [[0.0194, 0.0207, 0.0135, 0.0225, 0.0234, 0.0619, 0.0226],
         [0.0739, 0.0291, 0.0200, 0.0308, 0.0395, 0.0124, 0.0594],
         [0.0171, 0.0248, 0.0250, 0.0572, 0.0387, 0.0392, 0.0343],
         [0.0235, 0.0282, 0.0202, 0.0183, 0.0332, 0.0785, 0.0225],
         [0.0128, 0.0335, 0.0314, 0.0407, 0.0954, 0.0246, 0.0475],
         [0.0285, 0.0138, 0.0187, 0.1018, 0.1017, 0.0324, 0.0281],
         [0.0270, 0.0170, 0.0209, 0.0646, 0.0445, 0.0507, 0.0332],
         [0.0344, 0.0162, 0.0201, 0.0440, 0.0258, 0.0451, 0.0349],
         [0.0316, 0.0138, 0.0181, 0.0321, 0.0197, 0.0420, 0.0464],
         [0.0542, 0.0156, 0.0196, 0.0350, 0.0183, 0.0310, 0.0502],
         [0.0379, 0.0182, 0.0210, 0.0510, 0.0309, 0.0407, 0.0350],
         [0.0143, 0.0164, 0.0405, 0.0197, 0.0563, 0.0460, 0.0740],
         [0.0305, 0.0114, 0.0246, 0.0487, 0.0253, 0.0321, 0.0262],
         [0.0614, 0.0173, 0.0497, 0.0193, 0.0278, 0.0194, 0.0703],
         [0.0304, 0.0183, 0.0203, 0.0693, 0.0465, 0.0436, 0.0310],
         [0.0233, 0.0106, 0.0215, 0.0546, 0.0365, 0.0704, 0.0316],
         [0.0161, 0.0147, 0.0213, 0.0662, 0.0604, 0.0597, 0.0292],
         [0.0355, 0.0182, 0.0235, 0.1025, 0.0758, 0.0262, 0.0298],
         [0.0243, 0.0194, 0.0207, 0.0816, 0.0617, 0.0465, 0.0268],
         [0.0229, 0.0179, 0.0126, 0.1265, 0.0750, 0.0587, 0.0194],
         [0.0342, 0.0349, 0.0214, 0.0760, 0.1028, 0.0220, 0.0328],
         [0.0154, 0.0176, 0.0177, 0.0921, 0.1138, 0.0400, 0.0276],
         [0.0278, 0.0517, 0.0190, 0.0199, 0.0227, 0.0622, 0.0200],
         [0.0211, 0.0195, 0.0171, 0.1059, 0.0813, 0.0448, 0.0222]],

        [[0.0781, 0.0383, 0.0384, 0.0767, 0.0456, 0.0623, 0.0667],
         [0.0855, 0.0636, 0.0529, 0.0739, 0.0949, 0.0350, 0.0862],
         [0.0366, 0.0318, 0.0470, 0.0706, 0.0951, 0.0597, 0.0834],
         [0.0609, 0.1179, 0.0466, 0.0197, 0.0283, 0.0774, 0.0499],
         [0.0421, 0.0414, 0.0483, 0.1358, 0.1277, 0.0716, 0.0526],
         [0.0701, 0.1052, 0.0321, 0.0556, 0.0622, 0.0707, 0.0316],
         [0.1205, 0.0823, 0.0520, 0.0741, 0.0896, 0.0201, 0.0812],
         [0.0708, 0.0906, 0.0612, 0.1050, 0.0872, 0.0300, 0.0536],
         [0.0756, 0.0838, 0.0589, 0.0753, 0.0873, 0.0397, 0.0454],
         [0.0627, 0.0833, 0.0629, 0.0969, 0.1090, 0.0279, 0.0610],
         [0.0718, 0.0559, 0.0531, 0.1245, 0.1142, 0.0323, 0.0517],
         [0.0701, 0.0725, 0.0601, 0.1100, 0.1037, 0.0286, 0.0558],
         [0.0659, 0.0613, 0.0538, 0.1447, 0.1049, 0.0356, 0.0451],
         [0.0589, 0.0890, 0.0455, 0.1189, 0.1162, 0.0328, 0.0494],
         [0.1026, 0.0700, 0.0565, 0.1031, 0.0814, 0.0241, 0.0531],
         [0.0815, 0.0676, 0.0560, 0.1157, 0.0919, 0.0293, 0.0512],
         [0.0632, 0.0711, 0.0768, 0.0742, 0.1056, 0.0290, 0.0787],
         [0.0862, 0.0618, 0.0576, 0.1152, 0.0873, 0.0287, 0.0487],
         [0.1240, 0.0520, 0.0925, 0.0486, 0.0633, 0.0221, 0.0928],
         [0.0849, 0.0688, 0.0552, 0.1114, 0.0931, 0.0282, 0.0530],
         [0.0754, 0.0464, 0.0557, 0.1264, 0.0801, 0.0450, 0.0518],
         [0.0782, 0.0673, 0.0561, 0.1118, 0.0915, 0.0314, 0.0519],
         [0.0851, 0.0652, 0.0565, 0.1111, 0.0927, 0.0283, 0.0530],
         [0.0911, 0.0935, 0.0428, 0.0950, 0.0721, 0.0256, 0.0382]]]), x=None, index=None, decoder_lengths=None, y=(tensor([[0.0103, 0.0083, 0.0082, 0.0110, 0.0209, 0.0499, 0.0844, 0.0694, 0.0664,
         0.0675, 0.0656, 0.0637, 0.0644, 0.0646, 0.0611, 0.0610, 0.0605, 0.0623,
         0.0511, 0.0381, 0.0336, 0.0278, 0.0195, 0.0142],
        [0.0060, 0.0043, 0.0042, 0.0087, 0.0233, 0.0597, 0.0882, 0.1922, 0.1318,
         0.0784, 0.0587, 0.0512, 0.0509, 0.0577, 0.0593, 0.0496, 0.0442, 0.0444,
         0.0364, 0.0301, 0.0266, 0.0260, 0.0205, 0.0131],
        [0.0765, 0.0648, 0.0575, 0.0474, 0.0348, 0.0228, 0.0164, 0.0153, 0.0116,
         0.0114, 0.0186, 0.0251, 0.0390, 0.0519, 0.0647, 0.0691, 0.0775, 0.0855,
         0.0845, 0.0934, 0.0910, 0.0942, 0.1637, 0.0794]]), None))


and
predictions = tft.predict(test_dataloader, mode = "prediction", return_y=False)

which gives:
INFO: GPU available: False, used: False
INFO:lightning.pytorch.utilities.rank_zero:GPU available: False, used: False
INFO: TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
INFO:lightning.pytorch.utilities.rank_zero:TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
INFO: HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
INFO:lightning.pytorch.utilities.rank_zero:HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
tensor([[0.0362, 0.0446, 0.0653, 0.0317, 0.0526, 0.0922, 0.0779, 0.0567, 0.0580,
         0.0467, 0.0672, 0.0340, 0.0563, 0.0323, 0.0680, 0.0614, 0.0633, 0.0769,
         0.0680, 0.0855, 0.0756, 0.0827, 0.0338, 0.0950],
        [0.0225, 0.0308, 0.0572, 0.0183, 0.0407, 0.1018, 0.0646, 0.0440, 0.0321,
         0.0350, 0.0510, 0.0197, 0.0487, 0.0193, 0.0693, 0.0546, 0.0662, 0.1025,
         0.0816, 0.1265, 0.0760, 0.0921, 0.0199, 0.1059],
        [0.0767, 0.0739, 0.0706, 0.0197, 0.1358, 0.0556, 0.0741, 0.1050, 0.0753,
         0.0969, 0.1245, 0.1100, 0.1447, 0.1189, 0.1031, 0.1157, 0.0742, 0.1152,
         0.0486, 0.1114, 0.1264, 0.1118, 0.1111, 0.0950]])```

This doesn't run but I think it doesn't make sense to predict on test when train hasn't been fit but I don't understand how this model works.
 model = trainer.fit(
    tft,

    train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,

    val_dataloaders=test_dataloader,
)
predictions = model.predict(test_dataloader, mode = "quantiles", return_y=True)


